# How to prevent RecyclerView from moving items?

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, gridlayoutmanager

I'm trying to implement a layout which is basically a grid of items of the same size.

The items are ordered, there are dates on it like in a calendar, so you can why I can't have them randomly sorted every time I scroll.

My question is: Is there a way to prevent this behaviour or should I just stick with the old GridLayout?

I'm asking this also because I initially thought that the new RecyclerView was meant to be used just for randomly sorted items, such as news articles or posts. That would have explained the difficulties to control its behaviour.

However, after some reading and web-searching, it now seems to me, correct me if I'm wrong, that RecyclerView is an upgraded version of ListView, GridLayout and few others that are implemented by its LayoutManagers.

Can someone help me with this?

Thanks!

**EDIT:** This is my adapter:

```
public class CardAssenzeAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<CardAssenzeAdapter.AssenzeViewHolder> {

private List<Assenza> list;
Context c;

public CardAssenzeAdapter(Context c, List<Assenza> list) {
    this.c = c;
    this.list=list;
}

@Override
public int getItemCount() {
    return list.size();
}

@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(AssenzeViewHolder NewsViewHolder, int i) {

    Assenza n = list.get(i);
    AssenzeViewHolder.month.setText(n.getMeseS());
    AssenzeViewHolder.day.setText(n.getGiornoS());
    if (n.isRitardo()) AssenzeViewHolder.hour.setText(n.getTipoR());
}

@Override
public AssenzeViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup viewGroup, int i) {
    View itemView = LayoutInflater.
            from(viewGroup.getContext()).
            inflate(R.layout.card, viewGroup, false);

    return new AssenzeViewHolder(itemView);
}

public static class AssenzeViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
    protected static TextView month;
    protected static TextView day;
    protected static TextView hour;

    public AssenzeViewHolder(View v) {
        super(v);
        month = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.meseA);
        day = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.giornoA);
        hour = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.oraR);
    }
}

}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

RecyclerView has nothing to do with Randomly ordered elements. It's purpose is more like about using the resources more efficiently. Here is the quote from Android Developer page,

> "*The RecyclerView widget is a more advanced and flexible version of
>   ListView. This widget is a container for displaying large data sets
>   that can be scrolled very efficiently by maintaining a limited number
>   of views. Use the RecyclerView widget when you have data collections
>   whose elements change at runtime based on user action or network
>   events.*"

Regarding to order of your items, it's all about the data set you provide to the RecyclerView. So if your dataset is not sorted by date, or etc., then what you need to do is to sort your data set and then attach them to the RecyclerView.

And [HERE](https://developer.android.com/training/material/lists-cards.html#RecyclerView) you can take a look on it's implementation.

Comment: My dataset is ordered. Problem is that while scrolling the items get reordered no matter what were the data bound to them. So if even if I start with an ordered "calendar", I end up scrolling a calendar with randomly ordered elements

Comment: I think I know what your issue is. If you can post your Adapter Class, then I can make it more clear.

Comment: @FrancescoAmbrosini your code looks like as it should be. But one thing caught my eyes, in onBindViewHolder method. You are using the Static way to reach your UI elements from your ViewHolder class. Can you try it with the actual instance of it ?

So for example instead of  `AssenzeViewHolder.month` , can you change it into `NewsViewHolder.month `. I think that could explain the issue. But I will try to run your code if that does not work.